# How to access to my upper root folders from public_html in my MVC PHP application

Tags: php, .htaccess, root, public

i had a web  application which all my folders was under the public_html like this:

public_html
   -pages
   -templates
   -includes
   -styles
   -scripts
   -images
    index.php

so my website worked perfect and in a live server(with php 5.2.17 version).but i wanted to swtich to an object oriented approach and changed everything and tried to learn and inspired from zend framework structure model so i changed my folders structure and it worked perfect locally in appache,new structure is this:

application
     -models
     -controllers
    -views
    -config
    -layouts
        -templates
library
    -functions
public_html
    -styles
    -scripts
    -images
     index.php

so,i transfer it to live server,and now my main application is out of root(public_html) and of course i can not access upper root folders(application,library) from  public_html and of course index.php by  ***url***.
i can include them but i need to access by ***url*** in an anchor tag  in case of for example  acceess my login.php inside views folder which is inside application folder.
also, need to access the controoler folder from my scripts folder via url(for ajax calls and so on).
i have read that i need to use .htaccess file but i do not know what rule i should use,where shall i put it in and how.please someone help me as i need it ergently.
please tell me what should i do?
regards

Comment: In the MVC model, you don't usually look to try and access a file inside your `views` folder directly with a URL.

Answer (score 2):

You're mistaken. Take a closer to look to any MVC framework (mentioned Zend, for example). Everything goes through the index.php inside the public folder. You do not need to access anything below the public folder via URL (actually it should be prohibited for security reasons). You access controllers' actions via your internal program structure and via rewrite rules. Usually, every request forcibly routed to index.php and then your application decides where it will go further.

Comment: thanks for quick answer.but i hav seperated my index parts as navbar.php footer.php and so on and in my navbar as my menu is there i need to refer to my index page which is index_view.php inside views folder and it gave its controller inside it by include also.could you tell me more because i did not exactly understand what you meant.i am very new to mvc.thanks

Comment: You can include your files inside PHP script doesn't matter where in the file system they are actually located. Why don't just include your navbar.php and footer.php inside the script? You don't need URL access to them.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the way CodeIgniter, an MVC framework, handles file routing in it's own [`index.php` file](https://github.com/adityamenon/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/index.php):

```
$system_path = 'system';
$application_folder = 'application';
$view_folder = '';

/*
 * ---------------------------------------------------------------
 *  Resolve the system path for increased reliability
 * ---------------------------------------------------------------
 */

    // Set the current directory correctly for CLI requests
    if (defined('STDIN'))
    {
        chdir(dirname(__FILE__));
    }

    if (($_temp = realpath($system_path)) !== FALSE)
    {
        $system_path = $_temp.'/';
    }
    else
    {
        // Ensure there's a trailing slash
        $system_path = rtrim($system_path, '/').'/';
    }

    // Is the system path correct?
    if ( ! is_dir($system_path))
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
        exit('Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: '.pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME));
    }

/*
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  Now that we know the path, set the main path constants
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
    // The name of THIS file
    define('SELF', pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME));

    // Path to the system folder
    define('BASEPATH', str_replace('\\', '/', $system_path));

    // Path to the front controller (this file)
    define('FCPATH', str_replace(SELF, '', __FILE__));

    // Name of the "system folder"
    define('SYSDIR', trim(strrchr(trim(BASEPATH, '/'), '/'), '/'));

    // The path to the "application" folder
    if (is_dir($application_folder))
    {
        if (($_temp = realpath($application_folder)) !== FALSE)
        {
            $application_folder = $_temp;
        }

        define('APPPATH', $application_folder.'/');
    }
    else
    {
        if ( ! is_dir(BASEPATH.$application_folder.'/'))
        {
            header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
            exit('Your application folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: '.SELF);
        }

        define('APPPATH', BASEPATH.$application_folder.'/');
    }

    // The path to the "views" folder
    if ( ! is_dir($view_folder))
    {
        if ( ! empty($view_folder) && is_dir(APPPATH.$view_folder.'/'))
        {
            $view_folder = APPPATH.$view_folder;
        }
        elseif ( ! is_dir(APPPATH.'views/'))
        {
            header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
            exit('Your view folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: '.SELF);
        }
        else
        {
            $view_folder = APPPATH.'views';
        }
    }

    if (($_temp = realpath($view_folder)) !== FALSE)
    {
        $view_folder = realpath($view_folder).'/';
    }
    else
    {
        $view_folder = rtrim($view_folder, '/').'/';
    }

    define('VIEWPATH', $view_folder);
```

You should not depend on `.htaccess`, you might run into issues with environments where `mod_rewrite` is not available.

Additionally, don't load files in your `views/` directory from a Hyperlink. Route all those requests for pages from index.php into your `controllers/`, and *then* use those classes to load files. Look closely at CodeIgniter's source again for ideas.